# Joining tables with Compound Keys in JPA/Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, join, compound-key

Okay, our DB team has come up with the following structure.  I cannot change it:

**Report**

- has Reference Number (REF_NR) as its PID
- plus some data about the report, report date and so on

**Property**

- has Reference Number (REF_NR) *and* Building Number (BLG_NR) as its compound PID.  The REF_NR of the Report will match the REF_NR of all the Properties on the report, who are further indexed by their BLG_NR.
- plus some data about the build, square footage and so on

**Construction Data**

- has Reference Number (REF_NR), Building Number (BLG_NR), Structure Type Code (STRCT_TYP_CD) and Material Type Code (MTRL_TYP_CD)
- has a value which generally expresses the %ge of the given structure type that is the given material type.  For example, 50% of the ROOF is SLATE and 50% of the ROOF is TILE, and so on

I am trying to join these together to bring in the Report, all associated buildings and all construction data for each building, but I am pretty much a noob to JPA & hibernate annotations.

So, please help me determine the proper classes and annotations for joining these things together.  Or even just a good link to a really good example would help.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="RCT_REPORT")
public class Report implements Serializable {
    private Set<Building> buildings;
    private long referenceNumber;

    @Id
    @Column(name="REF_NR")
    public long getReferenceNumber() {
        return this.referenceNumber;
    }
    public void setReferenceNumber(long referenceNumber) {
        this.referenceNumber = referenceNumber;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="report", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    public Set<Building> getBuildings() {
        return this.buildings;
    }
    public void setBuildings(Set<Building> buildings) {
        this.buildings = buildings;
    }   
}

@Entity
@Table(name="RCT_BUILDING")
public class Building implements Serializable {
    private Report report;
    private Set<ConstructionData> constructionData;
    private BuildingPK id;

    @EmbeddedId
    public BuildingPK getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(BuildingPK id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="REF_NR", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    public Report getReport() {
        return this.report;
    }
    public void setReport(Report report) {
        this.report = report;
    }   

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="building", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumns ({
        @JoinColumn(name="REF_NR", referencedColumnName = "REF_NR"),
        @JoinColumn(name="BLG_NR", referencedColumnName = "BLG_NR")
    })
    public Set<ConstructionData> getConstructionData() {
        return this.constructionData;
    }

    public void setConstructionData(Set<ConstructionData> constructionData) {
        this.constructionData = constructionData;
    }   
}

@Embeddable
public class BuildingPK implements Serializable {
    private long referenceNumber;
    private int buildingNumber;

    @Column(name="REF_NR")
    public long getReferenceNumber() {
        return this.referenceNumber;
    }
    public void setReferenceNumber(long referenceNumber) {
        this.referenceNumber = referenceNumber;
    }

    @Column(name="BLG_NR")
    public int getBuildingNumber() {
        return this.buildingNumber;
    }
    public void setBuildingNumber(int buildingNumber) {
        this.buildingNumber = buildingNumber;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        ...
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        ...
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name="CNSTRCTN_DATA")
public class ConstructionData implements Serializable {
    private ConstructionDataPK id;
    private BigDecimal value;
    private Building building;

    @EmbeddedId
    public ConstructionDataPK getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setId(ConstructionDataPK id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    @Column(name="MTRL_SEL_VAL")
    public BigDecimal getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
    public void setValue(BigDecimal value) {
        this.value = value;
    }


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns ({
        @JoinColumn(name="REF_NR", referencedColumnName="REF_NR", insertable=false, updatable=false),
        @JoinColumn(name="BLG_NR", referencedColumnName="BLG_NR", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    })
    public Building getBuilding() {
        return this.building;
    }

    public void setBuilding(Building building) {
        this.Building = building;
    }   
}

@Embeddable
public class ConstructionDataPK implements Serializable {
    private long referenceNumber;
    private int buildingNumber;
    private String structureTypeCode;
    private String materialTypeCode;

    @Column(name="REF_NR")
    public long getReferenceNumber() {
        return this.referenceNumber;
    }
    public void setReferenceNumber(long referenceNumber) {
        this.referenceNumber = referenceNumber;
    }

    @Column(name="BLG_NR")
    public int getbuildingNumber() {
        return this.buildingNumber;
    }
    public void setbuildingNumber(int buildingNumber) {
        this.buildingNumber = buildingNumber;
    }

    @Column(name="STRCT_TYP_CD")
    public String getStructureTypeCode() {
        return this.structureTypeCode;
    }
    public void setStructureTypeCode(String structureTypeCode) {
        this.structureTypeCode = structureTypeCode;
    }

    @Column(name="MTRL_TYP_CD")
    public String getMaterialTypeCode() {
        return this.materialTypeCode;
    }
    public void setMaterialTypeCode(String materialTypeCode) {
        this.materialTypeCode = materialTypeCode;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        ...
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        ...
    }
}
```

As I said, I'm pretty new to this, and this all looks right to me, but I'm sure I'm missing something.
Thanks!
Peter

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't really need bi-directionality.  That seems like it might be making this more complicated than I need.

Comment: 15 views and not a single answer? Really?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the join columns belong on the 'child' in the relationship, not the parent.  I had them in both places.

Also, although it doesn't show it, I had another problem where hibernate 3.3.2 doesn't like it if you only try to map part of a compound key.  In my real problem, there was a third field in the PK of the parent that was also in the child & I didn't have that mapped in the join table.  Once I added it, everything joined up just fine.

Peter